# Simplifying equation with maximum inside absolute sign

Tags: neural-networks, relu

This is the formula I am working on.

$|a\times \max(x,0)+b\times \max(y,0)+c \times \max(z,0)|$

Is it possible to take the maximum out of the absolute sign?

Comment: No. That expression will not be equal to max(0, |ax +by+ cz|) in general.  Give it a try with x=1, y =-1, z = 0.